# JasperServer dynamic Band Height as Subreports have different heights

Tags: jasper-reports, subreport

I have a jrmxl report that uses different subreports with different heights, one is 421 and the other one is 600.

Is it possible for the report to dynamically set the band height on each page of the PDF that it generates?

```
<detail>
    <band height="421">
        <subreport>
            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="297" height="421" uuid="a23ff576-6d38-4582-a7ea-18e18926136c"/>
            <subreportParameter name="NUMBER">
                <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$F{number}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
            </subreportParameter>
            <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
            <subreportExpression><![CDATA[$F{report}.trim()]]></subreportExpression>
        </subreport>
    </band>
</detail>
```

Comment: Your question is unclear, can not understand exactly what you are asking, you can not set dynamic band height directly but you can stretch objects, hence including your subreport in main report with height 10 it will stretch the band to the subreport heights..

Comment: My apologies for not being clear.

I have a number of sub reports that are used to generate a PDF. The sub reports can be different sizes.

What i'm trying to do is to generate the PDF so that each page generated height is as per the size in the sub report.

From your response, you seem to suggest that i should set the Band height to 421 (the smallest height) and then when the report uses the sub report with height of 600 that the band would stretch to match the sub report height?

Comment: Exactly you can set band height 10 in a main report, if the subreport have a totale height of 100 the band will be stretch to fit the subreport. In general you try to keep the band heights to minimum and then use the stretch feature of jasper report, to increase the size when needed.

Comment: To be honest I still don't really understand, generate a pdf where every page has a different height?? or are you trying to page break you sub report result in different pages?.

Comment: As you question is you  would need to setup different jrxml files with different page heights and then merge them on export, probably the best would be through the JasperPrint.

Comment: The report will have the sub reports pages grouped together (each sub report generates a new page). I'm using JasperServer and yes i do have seperate jrxml files for each sub report.

Comment: but the size of the page in pdf will always be the same.. example A4, I can't understand if you like different size on each page of pdf (example first page A4, second page A2) or if you are trying to page break this way?

Comment: In most cases the page size would be the same, the PDF contains shipment labels so they are not A4, could be B6 & B5. So yes want to page break the report based on page size. I know it sounds like weird a setup.

Answer (score 0):

If your subreports need to produce pages of different sizes in the same resulting PDF document, then you need to use your subreport templates as parts in a part-based JRXML, AKA book report, as opposed to the usual band-based JRXML.
You can find a book report sample in our project distro under the [/demo/samples/book](https://sourceforge.net/p/jasperreports/code/ci/master/tree/jasperreports/demo/samples/book/) folder.
Make sure you use JR Lib version 6.0.0 or newer.